# Detect Tap on UIImageView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to register a tap inside an UIScrollView but can't seem to get it work. I tried everything I've found on here to no success. I'm using a subclass of UIImageView to add an identifier to it which shouldn't be the problem. Can't seem to get it to work with the default UIImageView class either. "didTapImage" just does not get executed no matter what I do.

```
func fillSelectionView(){
    let imageNameArray = ["entdecken", "erleben", "erinnern"]

    imageArray = [UIImage(named: imageNameArray[0]), UIImage(named: imageNameArray[1]), UIImage(named: imageNameArray[2])] as! [UIImage]

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageViewWithIdentifier()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.setIdentifier(ident: imageNameArray[i])
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("didTapImage"))))


        let xPosition = self.selectionView.frame.width * CGFloat(Double(i))
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: selectionView.frame.width, height: selectionView.frame.height)
        selectionView.contentSize.width = self.selectionView.frame.width * CGFloat((Double(i) + 1))
        selectionView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}

func didTapImage(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let point = gesture.location(in: gesture.view)
    let imageViewTouched = gesture.view as! UIImageViewWithIdentifier
    let imageViewIdent = imageViewTouched.getIdentifier()

    print(point)
    print("touched" + imageViewIdent)
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Omg it worked! Thank you very very much. I'm so stupid.

Comment: You are welcome, you not stupid, you are just gaining experience as everybody! ;)

Comment: What's the version of swift you are typing? (`#selector` instead of `Selector`)? However, I'd assume that your code should work!

Comment: Had to change it to #selector to get it working. It's working like a charm now! Thank you

Comment: I’m not disappointed, but I was writing an answer lol; glad Francesco was able to help